# How to link child views of ListViews with an arrow view in android studio?

Tags: android, listview

I have a ViewGroup which contains a bunch of listViews ordered horizontally. What I need is when I Longclick on a ListView ChildView, I can can select another childView of another ListView only and connect two views together with an arrow similar to the way it works in labView block diagrams (see image below)  where you drag an arrow and attach it from one item to another...

[LabView block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3j1An.jpg)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
//ViewGroup where listViews are added dynamically 
  <CustomViewGroup
            android:id="@+id/list_layout_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            />

            </CustomViewGroup>
```

//MainActivity code -- clicking on item inside a listView

```
    @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


            ListView listFrom = null; 
            ListView listTo = null;
            String nodeToName = null;
            String nodeFromName = null; 


            Log.e("onItemLongClick", "Long CLick");


            NodeItems current = (NodeItems) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);


       // First childView selected -- i.e. the item first clicked on
            View rowView = parent.getChildAt(position);


            /** Extract position of the first ChildView item **/

            if (rowView != null) {


                listFrom = (ListView) rowView.getParent();


                Log.e("Send Node position", current.getNodeTask().toString());


                int[] locations = new int[2];

                rowView.getLocationOnScreen(locations);//Get location of first View 

                /** Extract position of the nodeTo item **/

                try {


                    // Let user know to select another node
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please select another Node: ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //Elapsed time to get focus on new child
                    Thread.sleep(3000);

                    //Click on the second view that user wants to connect which belongs to another listView and store in a temp view variable
                    View nodeView = getCurrentFocus();

                    int[] map = new int[2];


                    if (nodeView != null && nodeView.getParent() instanceof ListView && nodeView != rowView) {

                        nodeView.getLocationOnScreen(map); //get location of second View


                        listTo = (ListView) nodeView.getParent();


                        for (int i = 0; i < listTo.getChildCount(); i++) {

                            if (listTo.getChildAt(i) == nodeView) {

                                nodeTaskToName = ((Node) listTo.getNodeAdapter().getItem(i)).getTaskName();


                            }


                        }


                    }



                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                if (nodeFromName != null && nodeToName != null) {
                    connectNodes(listFrom, listTo, nodeFromName,  nodeToName); //Method connects nodes in a HashMap 


                /** Call another method to add arrow between two methods onTouch based on the two locations **/

           //have no idea how to do this 
                } 







        return true;
    }
```

Comment: can you post sample code please

Comment: Hi @OmarAlHalabi ! Have u had any chance to look at my code...